# Which countries are on track to fulfill their Nationally Determined Contributions(NDCs)?

Tags: united-nations, climate-change, paris-agreement

[United Nations' definition of NDC](https://www.un.org/en/climatechange/all-about-ndcs):

> Simply put, an NDC, or Nationally Determined Contribution, is a climate action plan to cut emissions and adapt to climate impacts. Each Party to the **Paris Agreement** is required to establish an NDC and update it every five years.

What I want to know is that, are countries actually fulfilling the NDCs that they set themselves?
Which countries are on track to fulfill their  NDCs and which ones are quite behind the schedule?